# Barcode Height missing from Custom Barcode Entry

Tags: java, barcode, fedex

I am integrating FedEx shipping API to generate labels using Java. Everything is working fine, but except for this issue. I am receiving the following error when setting `LabelFormatType` to `COMMON2D` or `LABEL_DATA_ONLY` for FedEx Freight i.e `FEDEX_FREIGHT_ECONOMY` and `FEDEX_FREIGHT_PRIORITY`.

```
        <Code>6022</Code>
        <Message>Barcode Height missing from Custom Barcode Entry</Message>
```

I did try to add Barcode height in fields below, but its not working

```
RequestedShipment -> ShippingDocumentSpecification -> CustomShipmentDocumentDetail -> CustomContent -> BarcodeEntries -> BarHeight

RequestedShipment -> ShippingDocumentSpecification -> CustomPackageDocumentDetail -> CustomContent -> BarcodeEntries -> BarHeight

RequestedShipment -> ShippingDocumentSpecification -> FreightAddressLabelDetail -> CustomContent -> BarcodeEntries -> BarHeight

RequestedShipment -> LabelSpecification -> CustomerSpecifiedDetail -> CustomContent -> BarcodeEntries -> BarHeight
```

Note: The code is working for other two `LabelFormatType`i.e `FEDEX_FREIGHT_STRAIGHT_BILL_OF_LADING` and `VICS_BILL_OF_LADING` and other `ServiceTypes`.

I am unable to find any solution yet.

Please let me know what am I missing ?

Answer (score 2):

You were right, you need to use those 2 label format types. When it comes to LTL Freight shipment request, the *"Barcode Height missing from Custom Barcode Entry"* can be returned when using `COMMON2D` or `LABEL_DATA_ONLY`. As per FedEx support, the FedEx LTL shipments require a Bill-Of-Lading (BOL) and the only `LabelFormatTypes` available for this are either the `FEDEX_FREIGHT_STRAIGHT_BILL_OF_LADING` or `VICS_BILL_OF_LADING where VICS` = Voluntary Inter-Industry Commerce Standards. 
This label is returned in PDF format, besides that you can request a FedEx Address Label in ZPL format.